# Maven project with local file dependency build error 501

Tags: java, maven, local

I've got maven project with local dependencies, which doesn't compile because this 'improvement', introduced by maven:

> Effective January 15, 2020, The Central Repository no longer supports
>   insecure communication over plain HTTP and requires that all requests
>   to the repository are encrypted over HTTPS.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
...
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>in-project</id>
        <name>In Project Repo</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
...
```

So now I'm receiving the following compile error:

> Could not resolve dependencies for project ........:war:1.0: Failed to
>   collect dependencies for [.........:jar:1.0 (compile),
>   javax:javaee-web-api:jar:7.0 (provided), .........:jar:1.0
>   (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   .........:jar:1.0: Could not transfer artifact
>   .........:pom:1.0 from/to central
>   (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file:
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/..../..../1.0/.....-1.0.pom.
>   Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1]

As you can see I'm using local jar file, but this doesn't compile anymore

Does anyone have idea how to configure local repository for successful compilation?

Comment: What maven version are you using?

Comment: And have you configured maven in your settings xml in _MAVEN_HOME\conf\settings.xml_?

Comment: It's maven 3.6, I haven't touched any settings

Answer (score 0):

The Maven server do not support HTTP anymore. You must configure the maven repositories with HTTPS url's in your local maven configuration file, in your home folder yourname/.m2/settings.xml.

Here is an example that you may copy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>artifactory</id>
         <repositories>
            <repository>
               <snapshots>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
               </snapshots>
               <id>central</id>
               <name>libs-release</name>
               <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
               <snapshots />
               <id>snapshots</id>
               <name>libs-snapshot</name>
               <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
         </repositories>
         <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
               <snapshots>
                  <enabled>false</enabled>
               </snapshots>
               <id>central</id>
               <name>plugins-release</name>
               <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
               <snapshots />
               <id>snapshots</id>
               <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
               <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
         </pluginRepositories>         
      </profile>
   </profiles>
   <activeProfiles>
      <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
   </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: This works great. I'm not sure why it affects my local repository though - it seems that maven tries to get dependencies from central repository first, then uses local.